# New Page (Template Studio) WinUI 3 - tags helper

Tags: winui-3

When I create a new Template Studio Page (WinUI 3) the tag helper does not work.

For Example I write

```xml
<TextBox
```

and it shows me "!{CDATA[]"

[image: New Template Studio Page]

If I create a Page without Template Studio there is no problem.
One of Template Studio Page fixed itself, but I do not remember how to do it. And now I want to fill a new page and have a problem with tag helper.

Comment: Since this is not really a WinUI3 problem, you should ask Template Studio about this https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/issues/4680

Answer (score 0):

The computer restart fixed the problem.
If I restart Visual Studio only there is a problem.